# How do I configure Wireshark to see only the problems?

Tags: networking, wireshark, debug

I know a bit about networks but I have so far failed to define a filter which removes all "good" traffic from the display (i.e. all packets that were replied, all data transfers which were completed successfully, all connections that were terminated successfully).

Since this seems a pretty obvious request, I'm surprised that there doesn't seem to be a simle solution. I've read [Only shown problematic packets in WireShark](https://superuser.com/questions/618998/only-shown-problematic-packets-in-wireshark) but apparently `expert.severity == error` is only for application level errors (like broken PNG images which it did find in my log).

What is the filter rule for bad IP packets (checksum errors, timeouts, unacknowledged packets, rejected connections, collisions, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do this, because this isn't something many people want.

Errors happen all the time. They are completely routine, and are recovered from automatically the vast majority of the time. If you showed all the things that could count as errors, it would be information overload and actually detract from your ability to quickly identify the real problems that actually impact users.

Comment: How is showing all the good packets enhancing my ability to identify the real problems?

Comment: They way I usually use, and see others use, sniffers is to filter for the protocols that could be involved in the particular problem we're investigating. So we see both good and bad packets from the traffic flows in question and that lets us see the difference between the working and failing cases.

Comment: I'm looking more for a "find unexpected problems" tool. In my case, I have a few network errors per day. The useless data is simply drowning out the few data points I need to see. But at least this would explain why there is no "help pinpoint problems" since you already know the problem.